# Seed does not run when entity framework migrations are applied automatically

Tags: database, entity-framework, migration, seed

When I deploy my app to our staging server, when it starts it checks the database and applies any migrations if necessary, but it does not run the Seed() method. I just changed the connection string to an empty database, restarted the app and it recreated the entire database, but no seed data.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to do anything special to get the Seed() to run when migrations are applied automatically/implicitly?

Everything runs as expected on my dev environment because I apply the migrations explicitly using update-database and Seed is run every time I call update-database.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same thing, I start with an empty database and run Update-Database it gets created without the seed, I then run Update-Database again and it adds the seed. Have you worked out how to get around this?